# How to plot with Scilab Jupiter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, scilab

I would like to utilize Jupyter Notebook for my Scilab environment. In addition to having Python 3.11 and Scilab 2023 installed, I've also added the Scilab kernel using the following command:

```
pip install scilab_kernel
```

However, I'm encountering issues with creating plots within Jupyter Notebook. It's important to note that I do not have administrative rights, but I found a workaround by setting the environment variable using the Windows Command Line as shown below:

```
setx SCILAB_EXECUTABLE C:\Tools\scilab-2023.1.0\bin\Scilex.exe
setx PATH "%SCILAB_EXECUTABLE%;%PATH%"
```

Unfortunately, I'm still unable to generate plots in Jupyter Notebook, and I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Scilab 'plot2d' function disabled in -nogui or -nwni mode.
```

I've tried using "WScilex.exe" instead of "Scilex.exe," but this opens the Scilab application each time I execute a cell in Jupyter Notebook using the following command:

```
setx SCILAB_EXECUTABLE C:\Tools\scilab-2023.1.0\bin\WScilex.exe
```

My questions are:

1. Which Scilab executable should I set for the `SCILAB_EXECUTABLE` variable?
2. How can I set options like `-nwin`?

Additionally, I've provided images and a PowerShell printout for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may sound peculiar, but following the installation of PyCharm, everything is now functioning precisely as anticipated. Perhaps it automatically updated all the Python packages.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue might be related to limitations in my user rights on this PC. If I can identify the root cause, I will definitely update you.

Interestingly, the process worked flawlessly on my home PC with the following steps:

1. Installed Python using `python-installer.exe`.
2. Installed the Scilab kernel with `pip install scilab_kernel`.
3. Installed Jupyter Notebook with `pip install jupyter`.
4. Set the `SCILAB_EXECUTABLE` variable to `WScilex-cli.exe`.
5. Added Scilab's binary directory to the system's PATH variable with these commands:

   ```
   set PATH=%PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES%\scilab-2023.1.0\bin\
   set PATH=%PATH%;SCILAB_EXECUTABLE
   ```

On my home PC, everything worked as expected, but on the current PC, I'm still encountering issues. Specifically, the SCILAB kernel status remains "Busy," and the elapsed time keeps counting endlessly. However, the Python kernel works perfectly fine.

Here's an image for reference:

[image]

I'll continue to investigate the issue and keep you updated on any developments.

Comment: WORKING PC: STILL not WORKING ------
SCILAB Kernel status: Busy 
Elapsed Time: endless counting 
|    |
Python Kernel works!

Answer (score 0):

Use `WScilex-cli.exe` instead of `Scilex.exe`.

Comment: Thank you Stéphane! You have these Cells in Jupyter notebook that you fill with scilab code. If you run the cell, it opens the Scilab Apllication each time Wcilex.exe. Nothing else is happening. Only if I set the SCILAB_EXECUTABLE Scilex.exe it is working as expected. But trying to plot something, following error appears
plot2d(x,y): Scilab 'plot2d' Funktion in -nogui oder -nwni Modus deaktiviert.
plot(x,y): Undefinierte Variable: plot

Comment: Try `WScilex-cli.exe`

Comment: Using WSCILEX-cli.exe: Nothings happens. Kernel stays bussy. I edited my first post, where you can find the PowerShell Output and a screenshot of my jupyter notebook

Comment: Seems that you have to click somewhere in the Jupyter window to say that the notebook is trusted.

Comment: Still not working. Jupyter Notebook is only working with |||  setx SCILAB_EXECUTABLE C:\Tools\scilab-2023.1.0\bin\Scilex.exe  ||| But than, get the ERROR: undefiend Variable: plot ||| Scilab 'plot2d' Function in -nogui or -nwni Modus deactivated ........... Can you get it running. Is it the possibility, that I do not have ADMIN Richts on my PC  .. I ll try later on my private machine.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions seamlessly in Jupyter Notebook, while Scilab encounters an issue. The evaluation process appears to be perpetually ongoing, as indicated by the persistent black circle cursor. No error messages are displayed in the Windows 10 x64 command window.

I followed the installation instructions meticulously through the command line. Interestingly, my colleague is not experiencing any problems, while I am unable to execute cell evaluations in Jupyter using the Scilab kernel.

I'm hopeful that someone can provide assistance in resolving this matter.

**Here is the sequence of steps I undertook for installation:**

Installed Scilab using scilab-2023.1.0.bin.x64.exe
Installed Python using python-installer.exe
Installed Jupyter using "pip install jupyter"
Installed the Scilab kernel for Jupyter using "pip install scilab_kernel"
Set the SCILAB_EXECUTABLE using "setx SCILAB_EXECUTABLE WScilex-cli.exe"
Appended the Scilab binary directory to the PATH using the following commands:

```
"setx PATH %PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES%\scilab-2023.1.0\bin"
"setx PATH %PATH%;SCILAB_EXECUTABLE"
```

Troubleshooting steps undertaken:

**Checked the Scilab kernel using "python -m scilab_kernel.check"**
Verified the list of installed kernels using "jupyter kernelspec list"
Versions and outputs:

```
Jupyter version: 1.0.0
Scilab kernel version: 0.9.10
Python version: 3.10.11
Output of "python -m scilab_kernel.check":

Scilab kernel version: 0.9.10
Metakernel version: 0.29.5
Python version: 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr 5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python path: C:\Users\kwas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
```

Establishing a connection to Scilab...
Connection with Scilab established
Scilab version: "2023.1.0.1684825887"
Installed Scilab version: scilab-2023.1.0

**Output of "pip show scilab_kernel":**

```
Name: scilab-kernel
Version: 0.9.10
Summary: A Jupyter kernel for Scilab.
Home-page: http://github.com/calsto/scilab_kernel
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\kwas\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: ipykernel, jupyter-client, metakernel
Required-by:
```

**Output of "jupyter kernelspec list":**

Available kernels:

```
python3: c:\users\kwas\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
scilab: c:\users\kwas\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\share\jupyter\kernels\scilab
```